# Laravel Relations and Foreign Key Constraints

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration, relationship

I have two models and migrations tables.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Room extends Model
{
    public function guest()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Guest::class);
    }
}
```

-

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Guest extends Model
{
    public function room()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Room::class);
    }
}
```

room -> id, squaremeters, guest_id

guest -> id, Name, last_name, email, phone, room_id(required)

Room hasOne Guest -> implemented in the model

Guest hasMany Rooms -> implemented in the model

If I create a guest, I have to add a room Number. The room in room_table with the corresponding id should automatically be updated with the guest_id.

**Example**
new Guest: id(2), Name, last_name, phone, email, room_id(3) -> The room with id 3 should show to the Guest with id 2.

How do i implement this?

Comment: can you share you All related Model as well

Comment: what is actually you want to accomplish?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, one room can have only one guest at a time and one guest can book many rooms at a time?

Comment: @Mysteryos that's correct

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta I have two models:
room -> id, squaremeters, guest_id

guest -> id, Name, last_name, email, phone, room_id(required)

Room hasOne Guest -> implemented in the model

Guest hasMany Rooms -> implemented in the model

Comment: show your model first

Comment: @ShaielndraGupta I have addes it above

Comment: you don't need to save `room_id` in your `Guest Model` only required to store `guest_id` in you room model and when you call guset with its room itwill return guest with room

Answer (score 1):

**In your controller add this function:**

```
public function CheckInUser($guest_id,$room_id)

 $guest = Guest::where('id',$guest_id)->firstOrFail();
 $room = Room::where('id',$room_id)->firstOrFail();

 $guest['room_id'] = $room_id;
 $guest->save();

 $room['guest_id'] = $guest_id;
 $room->save();

}
```

**Now you can change a guest's room whenever you want by calling the function above as shown below:**

```
CheckInUser(2,3);
```

Comment: Do I have to add any foreign key constraints in the migrations table? What would be the benefit if I do?

Comment: You do not have to create any relationship between the guest and the room to use the function above.Therefore no foreign keys are needed.

Comment: While the code will work, it's preferable to use built-in eloquent methods to save your relationships. This goes in line with seperation of concerns where your implementation class must not know of the column names of your model

Answer (score 0):

**Room class**

```
class Room extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'room';

    /**
     * Relationship - Belongs To - Guest
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function guest()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Guest::class,'guest_id');
    }
}
```

**Guest class**

```
class Guest extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table='guest';

    /**
     * Relationship - Has Many - Rooms
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
     */
    public function rooms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Room::class,'guest_id');
    }
}
```

Code for saving the relationships defined above:

```
$room = Room::create();
$room->save();

$guest = Guest::create();
$guest->save();
//Add guest to room - 1st method
$guest->rooms()->save($room);

//Add guest to room - 2nd method
$room->guest()->associate($guest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Model Guest

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Guest extends Model
{
    public function room()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Room::class);
    }
}
```

and room model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Room extends Model
{
    public function guest()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Guest::class);
    }
}
```

in your Controller loadd all model in constructer

```
 $gust_id=$request->get('guest_id');
 $room_id=$request->get('count_of_rooms');
 $squrmtr=$request->get('squaremeters');
```

let you after saving guest data you have multiple rooms and you have to save it

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($request->get('count_of_rooms')); $i++)
{
    $rooms[] = new Room([
        'guset_id'  => $guest->id,
        'squaremeters' => $squrmtr[$i],
    ]);
}
$guest->room()->saveMany($rooms);
```